# Salesforce - Unable to create the parent and child records in single Salesforce API Create call

Tags: api, soap, salesforce

In order to create the Parent and child records in single salesforce API Create call I should set the MyExtId__c field. But How should I get this external field in Salesforce WSDL..

Please refer the below link for more info on Create Call..

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_create.htm   ( Creating Parent and Child Records in a Single Call Using Foreign Keys)

Please do help me at the earliest..

Regards
Deepa

Comment: what about using an external id you already know